# $y'=\sin^2(y-x)$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve $y'=\sin^2(y-x)$ and see how the solutions look like, but I have no experience with this short of trigonometric differential equation.

Should I simply try to integrate it like this?

$$\int dy=\int \sin^2(y-x)dx$$

Is there any other way of handling this type of equation?

Also, if I make $\sin^2(y-x)=k$, I only get a couple of lines in a short interval. How can I get more information in order to sketch the solutions?

Any hint would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $y(x)=x+z(x)$. Then
$$
1+z'=\sin^2 z\Longrightarrow z'=-\cos^2z
$$
Now separate variables:
$$
\int -\frac{dz}{\cos^2z} = x + C\\
-\tan z = x + C\\
\tan (x-y)=x+C
$$
Could you proceed?